# my for statement inside a service does not cycle.

Tags: android, json, for-loop, println

I have made a service to update my app, it should take a JSON from the net and if the data is new, it insert it in a database:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


            datasource = new pollDataSource(this);
            datasource.open();


            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);


            try {

                // Getting Array of Contacts
                domanda = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DOMANDE);
                System.out.println("inside the try");
                // looping through All Contacts
                System.out.println("length: " + domanda.length());
                for(int i = 0; i < domanda.length(); i++){
                    System.out.println("in the for!: " + i);
                    JSONObject c = domanda.getJSONObject(i);
                    System.out.println("raw: "+ c.getString(TAG_CATEGORIA));
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String testoDomanda = c.getString(TAG_TESTODOMANDA);
                    String categoria = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORIA);
                    int quanteRisposte = c.getInt(TAG_QUANTERISPOSTE);
                    System.out.println("string: "+categoria);

                    datasource.createCategoria(categoria);
                    //TEOTODO inserimento della categoria, se necessario
                    //TEOTODO inserimento della domanda                 


                    for(int ua = 0; ua < quanteRisposte; ua++){
                    //TEOTODO inserimento dei testi risposte.   

                    }



                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
              //  e.printStackTrace();
            }
...
```

the logcat of all the println is:

```
01-04 10:47:06.213: I/System.out(653): inside the try
01-04 10:47:06.223: I/System.out(653): length: 3
01-04 10:47:06.233: I/System.out(653): in the for!: 0
01-04 10:47:06.233: I/System.out(653): raw: zodiaco
01-04 10:47:26.773: I/System.out(653): inside the try
01-04 10:47:26.773: I/System.out(653): length: 3
01-04 10:47:26.773: I/System.out(653): in the for!: 0
01-04 10:47:26.785: I/System.out(653): raw: zodiaco
01-04 10:47:47.414: I/System.out(653): inside the try
01-04 10:47:47.423: I/System.out(653): length: 3
01-04 10:47:47.423: I/System.out(653): in the for!: 0
01-04 10:47:47.423: I/System.out(653): raw: zodiaco
01-04 10:48:07.963: I/System.out(653): inside the try
01-04 10:48:07.963: I/System.out(653): length: 3
01-04 10:48:07.963: I/System.out(653): in the for!: 0
01-04 10:48:07.973: I/System.out(653): raw: zodiaco
```

as you can see I have two problems, the first one, the for should do 3 iterations, but it only does one... why?

and the second, if i print out the raw data, i get the "zodiaco" which is a category i get from the net, but if I assign it to a string variable, well, the println simply ignore the whole line...anyone as an idea? :D

thanks in advance.

Comment: the logcat is ripetitive, becouse the service is started every 20 seconds (just for test now)

Comment: You probably get an exception in your for loop, which you have decided to ignore with an empty catch block.

Comment: that should be true, i asap implement the catch block, but why is the string empty? the reason was exactly that, thanks! if you want to write down the answer, i give you the acceptation :D

Comment: I have done that and added some details.

Answer (score 0):

You probably get an exception in your for loop, which you have decided to ignore with an empty catch block.

When dealing with exceptions, you generally have 2 possible situations:

- either you don't know what to do with it => don't catch it and let the calling code deal with it (if you want to avoid force closes, you will need to catch it at some stage though)
- or you can do something useful with it (like retry or let the user know that there is a problem) in which case you catch it and deal with it.

While you are still in development phase, simply logging can be good enough but at least you get a feedback on what is going on.

Merely swallowing exceptions with empty catch statements is (almost) never a good option.